# How to send html text to ASP.NET Generic Handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, html-parsing

I have a WYSIWYG editor on one of my forms and I want to send the contents of the editor to an ASP.NET generic handler for processing via an Ajax call.

I am having a little bit of trouble parsing the html received.

Client Side:

```
$(function(){
   $('.send').bind('click', function(event){

       var message = $('#TxtMessage').htmlarea('toHtmlString');
       message = escape(message);

       $.get('/Handlers/EmailHandler', { message: message }, function(data){

           if( data != null || data != '' )
           {
               var success = eval(data);

               if( success ){
                   alert('Email sent');
               }
           }
       });

    });
});
```

Server side:

```
public class EmailHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   {
       context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
       string message = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Params["message"]) ? string.Empty : context.Request.Params["message"].ToString());

       message = context.Server.HtmlDecode(message);

       //do whatever...
    }
}
```

So the problem is that even when I call `Server.HtmlDecode(string)` the message is garbled.

Any ideas on how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way of parsing string sent to the server via JavaScript by using `escape()` is to use `HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode()`;